# Android: how to force visibility of virtual buttons on devices without physical buttons?

Tags: java, android, keyboard

There are devices with physical buttons ( = hard back/home/menu keys) like the Samsung S7 and other devices without physical buttons like the S8.

When my app is used, I was wondering how to force the visibility of the bar of virtual buttons at the bottom of the screen on the devices without any physical buttons.

Thanks.

Comment: Well the menu key is dead-  Android OS no longer uses it (it has a task switcher button in its place).  But the Android OS itself displays the virtual keys-  there's no need for you to do so.

Comment: No, the virtual keys may be hidden on some dives like the S8. They can be scrolled from the bottom but this is not what I want. I want them to be visible when my app is used.